# Regular expression in Flex

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I want to check if the string is not empty (having whitespaces only also counts as empty). How to compose the regular expression in actionscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern should be something like `/^\s*$/` (for a single line string); `^` and `$` represent the start and end of the line and `\s*` means match zero or more whitespace characters. For example:

```
var s:String = /* ... */;
var allWhitespaceOrEmpty:RegExp = /^\s*$/;
if (allWhitespaceOrEmpty.test(s))
{
    // is empty or all whitespace
}
else
{
    // is non-empty with at least 1 non-whitespace char
}
```

Perhaps a simpler way as commenter Alexander Farber points out is to check for any character except a whitespace character, which is matched by `\S` in regex:

```
var nonWhitespaceChar:RegExp = /\S/;
if (nonWhitespaceChar.test(s))
{
    // is non-empty with at least 1 non-whitespace char
}
```

Comment: And for multiple line string, what would be the difference?

Comment: add the `(?s)` multi-line switch: `/(?s)^\s*$/`

Comment: So it will work for both single and multi line strings right?

Comment: A single string *is* a multi-line string where the number of lines is `1`, so yes

Comment: Checking for /\S+/ is more straightforward IMHO